# Rails and jQuery - trying to auto update data with setTimeout ajaxily

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a page that can be accessed in the browser `/calendar` which points to `calendar#index`.

I have a javascript `setTimeout` function which calls the `$.get` ajax method on the same function because i'm trying to just re-fetch the data with `$.get` and then update the data on my page with jQuery.

```
$.get("<%= calendar_path %>", function(data, status) {
    console.log('success');
}, "json").fail(function(data) {
    console.log('fail');
    console.log(data);
});
```

which calls my `calendar#index` method

```
...
respond_to do |format|
    format.js
        format.html # show.html.erb
end
```

which returns `/views/calendar/index.js.erb` which contains:

```
console.log('in js');
```

which gives this response in firebug console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/calendar 304 Not Modified 148ms   
fail
Object { readyState=4, responseText="console.log('in js');", status=200, more...}
```

The console.log from my index.js.erb file is never logged in the console. Why is this and why does my `$.get` call always fail?

Comment: Did you make sure that the server-log has no errors and it rendered the output correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery Ajax request expects the type of response. You have mentioned it as "json". Instead, it should be "script"